# How do I split train and test based on certain criteria in python in XGBoost?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I split my data into trainData and testData in the ratio 70:30 before running the XGB regressor model. I need to run this model repetitively. What do I need to do so that I get a different 70:30 split each time? I need t ensure that the 30% testData gets included in the trainData the next time I split before running it again.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i made a flag and initialised as 0. then ran xgb. out of the full data, i received values for 30% and initialised the flag to 1. How do i proceed for the next iteration so that i get values for a different 30% and thus get values for predicted cost for the entire data

Comment: Plz. put the code attempt in your question. You will then have more chances of getting help.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you would consider using cross-validation for that:
 http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html

Example:

```
import xgboost
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
dataset = load_iris()
X = dataset['data']
Y = dataset['target']
model = xgboost.XGBClassifier()
kfold = KFold(n_splits=4, random_state=1)
results = cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv=5)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, 
results.std()*100))
```

more examples you can find here (https://machinelearningmastery.com/evaluate-gradient-boosting-models-xgboost-python/)

or if you want 70 to 30 ratio then use: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: While links to a solution are fine please include the essential parts in your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is code with an example above is enough?